# Calling subprocess.Popen from Django

Tags: python, django

I use the following Python code in Django to run Perl scripts from Django.

```
def run_command(cmd, input_data=None):
    assert type(cmd) == list
    stdout = ''
    stderr = ''
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        bufsize=1000*1000,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if (input_data):
        p.stdin.write(input_data)
    p.stdin.close()
    log("closed stdin")
    stdout = p.stdout.read()
    log("read stdout")
    stderr = p.stderr.read()
    return (stdout, stderr)
```

After moving the code from Ubuntu `10:04` to `12:04` the call to `p.stdout.read()` has started failing now and then. When it fails the last thing I see in the log file is `closed stdin` and nginx display a `502 Bad Gateway` page.

Comment: Have you tried `stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input_data)`? btw, you could use `bufsize=-1` (system default).

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately still got the failure on p.communicate(input_data).

Comment: I don't get a traceback; when it fails I only see the nginx 502 Bad gateway page displayed. I don't get the normal Django page showing the traceback that I'd expect. I call the Perl script about 300+ times; perhaps this is too much when running under Django.

Comment: do you mean the process dies without  a traceback? (enable [faulthandler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/) in this case) otherwise configure django to log uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Have you checked server logs to see what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try to get a better look at the issue is to use Django's 'runserver' instead of Nginx temporarily. This will allow you to see the traceback on the page instead of the 502.

If you aren't sure how to do this, you can use the following example:

`python manage.py runserver 1.1.1.1:8080`

Where you can replace 1.1.1.1 with 'localhost' or an IP of your choosing, and 8080 can be replaced with whatever open non-privileged port you would like. You might need to modify your settings file to set `DEBUG=True`.